# How to place a button below a UITableView managed by UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a screen with a table view managed by a controller based on `UITableViewController`. I would now like to affix a button to the bottom of the screen so that it does *not* scroll along with the table view cells.

Replacing the `UITableViewController` with a plain `UIViewController` is not an option, as I want to include a `UIRefreshControl`. From what I have read, using a `UIRefreshControl` without a `UITableViewController` is currently not possible without resorting to any hacks / relying on undocumented behaviour.

I tried using a `UIToolbar` provided by the navigation controller which my table view controller is contained in, but there are two problems with that approach:

1. I only want the toolbar with the button to be present in the top level table view. However, I have not found an elegant way to only show the toolbar for the top level table view. I want the toolbar to animate out of the screen to the left together with the table view when I drill down.
2. I have not found a way to increase the height of the toolbar. Would I have to put the button in a dummy `UIView`?

This is approximately what I am aiming for:

http://pic.rockmynews.com/img/free-iphone-app.png

Another idea is using a container view controller containing the button at the bottom and the table view controller above it as its child view controller. But that seems a lot of work for something this simple.

So what is the best way to do this? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Create the `UIView` container view. But also create a `UIViewController` subclass to manage the container. Then, add your existing table view controller as a child view controller and add the table view as a subview. Now you can control all of the subviews and positions while still having automatic refresh control operation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and return a UIView for the desired button. and

```
tableView:heightForFooterInSection
```

and return the footer height

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't willing to use a container view controller, you could use a third-party pull to refresh control like https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh instead. This has the added benefit of being backwards compatible with iOS 5, if you want to support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UITableViewController`. Just override `viewDidLoad` and then resize the `tableView` to make room for your extra view and then add your view programmatically. Make sure to set the right resizing mask so that things look correct on different screen sizes. (Easily tested in the Simulator by trying it out on the iPhone4 and iPhone5)